# Java String.Matches();

Tags: java, regex, string, metacharacters

Why does the syntax below output false? I know that the `\\S` is a none white space character, and that the `\\w` is a word character.  Please feel free to tell me I'm wrong on that.  Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("asdfghj".matches("\\S\\w"));
```

Thanks.

Comment: `"asdfghj".matches("\\S\\w.*")` as `matches` will return true if it matches full input

Comment: `maches` checks if *entire* string can be matched by regex.